# Ticket to Ride Marklin vs. Germany Destination

Tags: ticket-to-ride, board-game-adaptations

I'm looking to recreate the Märklin version.

I need a list of which destination tickets are included. Does anyone have a list, or a picture like the one I took below of Germany?

[image]

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Or just support designers and publishers, no matter how successful, and buy a proper copy?

Comment: This could work as a fine question if you delete everything except the actual question in the second paragraph.

Comment: I don't fee that finding ways for people to create pirated versions of games is in scope for this site.

Comment: Agree with @JoeW and voting to delete - there's legal issues with this question

Comment: this game is OOP, with little hope of ever being reprinted

Answer (score 2):

> What I need help with is which destination tickets are included. Does anyone have a list, or a picture like the one I took below of Germany?

[Images can be found on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/21348/ticket-ride-marklin/images).

And a [spreadsheet of the info](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/17572/marklin-ticketsxls) can also be found on BGG.

Golden Tickets:
[image: Golden Tickets]

Silver Tickets:
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing downvoters are just letting their opinion of the question spill over to this answer, but in case there is any actual shortcoming with the answer: please let me know how the answer can be improved.

Comment: +1 to compensate. This information could be very helpful to identify missing tickets from an incomplete set.